# Example of non-polynomial functions on infinite ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory

I would like to finish the following exercise:

R is a infinite commutative ring with $1 \neq 0$.
We know that not every function $f:R \to R$ is a polynomial function (as opposed to when the ring is finite).
Give an example of $f:R\to R$ that is not a polynomial function (and proof that it's not a polynomial function).

My attempt:
For $x\neq 0$ we define $f(x)=\prod_{i=0}^{\infty}(a_i+(-x))$ where $-x$ is inverse element of $x$ with respect to $+$ operation and $a_i \in R, a_i\neq a_j$ for $i\neq j$. From this we know that $f(x)=0$ for infinitely many $x$.

And in this moment I have a question. ,,number of roots of polynomial $\leq$ degree of polynomial" does it always work for $R$ defined like that?

If yes, then $f$ got $\infty$ many roots so its either no-polynomial function or zero function (polynomial deg 0). So by defining $f(0)=1$ we know that it's not polynomial function.

Is this correct? Thanks in advance.

Next attempt, I will try to show that there is no polynomial equal to complex conjugation:
$f(a+bi)=\sum_{n=0}^{n'}(a_n+b_ni)(a+bi)^n$ for some $a_n,b_n\in \mathbb{R}$.
$(a+bi)^n=\sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k}a^{n-k}(bi)^k=\sum_{k=0}^{\lceil \frac{n-1}{2} \rceil} {n\choose 2k}a^{n-2k}b^{2k}(-1)^k+$ $+i\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor \frac{n-1}{2} \rfloor} {n\choose 2k+1}a^{n-(2k+1)}b^{2k+1}(-1)^k$

Thus

$Im(f(a+bi))=\sum_{n=0}^{n'}(a_n\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor \frac{n-1}{2} \rfloor} {n\choose 2k+1}a^{n-(2k+1)}b^{2k+1}(-1)^k)+$ $+(b_n \sum_{k=0}^{\lceil \frac{n-1}{2} \rceil} {n\choose 2k}a^{n-2k}b^{2k}(-1)^k)$

And

$Im(f(a-bi))=\sum_{n=0}^{n'}(-a_n\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor \frac{n-1}{2} \rfloor} {n\choose 2k+1}a^{n-(2k+1)}b^{2k+1}(-1)^k)+$ $+(b_n \sum_{k=0}^{\lceil \frac{n-1}{2} \rceil} {n\choose 2k}a^{n-2k}b^{2k}(-1)^k)$

And because $Im(f(a+bi))=-Im(f(a-bi))$ if we want it to be complex conjugation then every $b_n=0$, and by very simmular way we can show that every $a_n=0$ from $Re(f(a+bi))=Re(f(a-bi))$, thus $f(x)=0$, thus there is no polynomial equal to complex conjugation.
Is it correct now?

Comment: The property of "the number of roots of any polynomial is bounded by its degree" would require $R$ to be an integral domain, so you would need to specify $R$

Answer (score 2):

> Every function $R\to R$ is represented by a polynomial iff  $R$ is a finite field.

Let $f(0)=1, f(a)=0$ for $a\ne 0$.

If $R$ is a field then it is easy as polynomials have finitely many roots.

Otherwise take a non-unit $a$, if $f$ was a polynomial we'd have $f(a)\equiv f(0)\bmod (a)$.